# How much time do MS/PhD computer science students spend in internships, and when do they do internships during the year?

Tags: citations, internship

Is there any research/study/survey that tried to quantify:

1. How much time do MS/PhD computer science students spend in internships?
2. When do MS/PhD computer science students do internship during the year? (i.e., which months?)

Ideally, I would like a breakdown by country. I am mostly interested in PhD students in machine learning / natural language processing.

Comment: In the US, the answer to 2 is “May, June, July, and August.” This is due to the fact that US institutions have a long break over the (northern hemisphere) summer months and few breaks outside of that. In other countries this may be different.