# Is it reasonable to consider a back-up plan when my PhD student visa is still pending?

Tags: phd, communication, visa

I am an incoming international PhD student at a US university. Previously, I obtained my bachelor's degree from the same university, and I've recently completed my master's program at a university in the UK. Unfortunately, my student visa to return to the U.S. was refused for reasons beyond my control, and further administrative processing is required. With the fall semester approaching in just two weeks, this has left me feeling extremely stressed.

I've been in communication with my school and the program director, and they are willing to hold my place for a little longer while awaiting the visa outcome. But past experiences of others have shown that there's a chance of visa refusal or substantial delays in processing. This uncertainty has led me to contemplate internships as an alternative plan.

I reached out to a professor who I had worked with during my undergraduate years, and he has consented to provide me with a reference letter for internship applications. He's well-acquainted with me compared to other professors. However, since he's likely to be my PhD supervisor, I'm concerned that applying for an internship before the beginning of the fall semester might give the impression that I'm not entirely committed to our joint research project. My query is whether it's sensible to have a back-up plan while my PhD student visa remains pending. How might I convey to my professor that my commitment to working with him remains strong, provided that the visa issue is resolved?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

> Is it reasonable to consider a back-up plan when my PhD student visa is still pending?

Yes. Don't let discriminatory policies keep you out of work. The internship sounds like a great backup plan. PhD students in the US do internships [very often](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116341/452). Go for it.

> How might I convey to my professor that my commitment to working with him remains strong, provided that the visa issue is resolved?

You could start a side project with them with a small hour/week commitment, if you aren't in the US (otherwise it could violate your visa status). That being said, most PhD advisors should understand your situation and your interest in interning while your visa is being processed. If not, that's a red flag.

It's commonplace in the US for advisors to lose great students due to the current discriminatory policies of the government. I lost one last week, and one two months ago, for example.